# How to use setDisplayOptions method for action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want for an action bar to set:

```
 actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
 actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and in other place:

```
  actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
  actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

but using instead the `setDisplayOptions` method (which seems that is recommended when you want "to set several display options at once") but do not know how to use it ...

Answer (score 7):

Layout:

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/editField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textFilter" >

</EditText>
```

MainActivity:

```
    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);
        EditText edit= (EditText) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.editField);
        edit.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

          @Override
          public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
              KeyEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Execution started",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
          }
        });
 //here comes the usage of setDisplayOptions
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
      }

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, 
which is actually the equivalent for `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled` and `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`  methods in  `setDisplayOptions ` method ?